Children’s book about an evil computer
There’s a book my friend and I read in elementary school (in the 2010s) and we can’t find it for the life of us. It is a chapter book and was probably written in the early 2000s,maybe late 90s.
From what we remember, the main character is a young boy. There’s also his grandpa and a young girl that are prominent in the story. He has a computer, and it turns evil at some point because it creates an online version of him that tries to take over his life.
There might also be a school dance or game that’s a plot point. The cover has an old clunky computer and shows the evil version of the boy coming out of the screen. I might be adding this part in but I think he has a devious smirk on his face.

The book in question is Virtually Perfect by Dan Gutman.

Yip Turner spends more time playing computer games than with other kids. For him, virtual reality usually beats reality! So when his dad, a movie special-effects designer, brings home new software for creating virtual actors, Yip is psyched. He and his sister create "Victor," a boy who is smart, handsome, and charming-perfect in everyway. But when Victor leaves cyberspace and invades their world, Yip realizes that there are bugs in the virtual-actor software. Now his family-and possibly the whole country!-may be in danger….


